# Codeigniter: how to remove index.php from URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-3

I've looked at many articles and tried different ways but it still doesn't work.

Now my URLs look like `mysite.com/index.php/[controller]`.
The goal is `mysite.com/[controller]`.

In **config.php**:

```
$config['index_page'] = ""; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

My **.htaccess** file contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also **mod_rewrite** is enabled in my Apache server.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Are you using linux or windows operating system

Comment: Check [this](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) one.

Answer (score 1):

In `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

in `.htaccess` (Place Outside application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**Update 2018-02-27**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'; # Must fill
```

else you get this error [**Codeigniter echoing [::1] instead of localhost**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876187/codeigniter-echoing-1-instead-of-localhost/35876229#35876229)

use this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

[**Refference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your config file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['server_root'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working fine for me, you can try with this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me [in **linux operating system**]:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

in config file use your project url in base_url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project';
```