# Codeigniter echoing [::1] instead of localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-4

I am using CodeIgniter 3 as a web platform and trying to import semantic-UI CSS into my page. I'm doing so by using CodeIgniter's `base_url()` method in the `href` property for the CSS import.

However, semantic.css itself imports some other fonts on my server, which cannot load because of `Cross-Origin` resource sharing policy. This is the error message chrome gives me:

Font from origin '`http://[::1]`' has been blocked from loading by `Cross-Origin` Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

This is because base_url() echoes the domain has been `[::1]` and not localhost as I've typed into the browser.

For some reason, it appears to me that chrome (and also Edge) does not consider `[::1]` and localhost as the same host, or maybe I'm just being dumb. What I know though is that if I change the path of the main semantic.css file and complex code localhost into it, it works, and it also works if, instead of requesting my page using localhost, I use `[::1]`

I've done other projects very similar to this and never had this `"[::1]"` appear. What exactly is causing PHP to echo such a path?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's because of your `base_url` is empty.

In **config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name';
```

> Something more interesting about [`http://\[::1\]/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

Comment: Well I realize this, but I've never filled it in and the base_url has always been correctly resolved whether it was on localhost or some other domain.

If I filled this value in I would imagine I would need to change it when moving my project from my machine to some other server right ?

Comment: Some other server means??

Comment: If I moved to say example.com, would base_url still echo localhost had I set that ?

Comment: When you hosted it to live server, (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/) so you have to change baseurl as well

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, since It'll be quite often that I change this project from my machine to a live server I wanted to have all of this change automatically so both versions can be the same.

Answer (score 9):

You need to edit your **$config['base_url']** as follows,

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

*File location: codeigniter/application/config/config.php*

Use above code to get dynamic url.

Answer (score 7):

More accurate and dynamic way

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Though you can still use port.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use base_url(); you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in application/config/autoload.php (on or around line 67): or you can manually using

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

than set the

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_site_url';
```

i think it will help you

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to alter in config/config.php, it works properly in  "localhost" as well as in your "server":

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if(!defined('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',str_replace('application/config','',substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '/'))));

$config['base_path'] = constant("DOCUMENT_ROOT");

$config['js_url'] = $config['base_url'].'js/';

$config['css_url'] = $config['base_url'].'css/';

$config['image_url'] = $config['base_url'].'img/';

// Host resolution for cross origin requests

if(ENVIRONMENT == 'production') {
    $config['host'] = 'www.<domain_name>.com';
} else {

$config['host'] = 'localhost';

}
```