# Set up the base url in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, base-url

I have the directory structure like this in code igniter:

```
 Appsite
    -website
       -application
        -images
```

When I accessing the image in index.php I used:
`<img src="http://localhost/Appsite/website/images/images.PNG"`

And the href is:
 `<li class=""><a href="http://localhos/tAppsite/website/index.php/home/">Home</a></li>`

I think it is not a good practice to include the `http://localhost` when accessing the images or libraries in code igniter. So I tried to change the `$config['base_url']`  in `config.php` 
to `$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/";`

And now I update my image source and other library source I remove the localhost and the name of my directory folder:

`<img src="images/images.PNG”>`
`<li class=""><a href= <?php echo base_url;?>  /website/index.php/home/">Home</a></li>`

But I get errors. it says object not found. Can some help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Appsite/website/';
$config['index_page'] = '';

# If online site
# $config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
```

**In `.htaccess` (outside application folder)** - To remove `index.php` in URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

**To accessing URL**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>contollerName/methodName"> click here</a>
```

**To access image**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/images.PNG”>
```

**To access CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css"/>
```

---

To use `base_url` load URL helper from autoload.php

Comment: What do you mean by To use base_url load URL helper from autoload.php?

Comment: if you use `base_url` its gives you error. So go to `config/autoload.php` and load URL in helper

Comment: Do you mean like this `$autoload['helper'] = array('form','url');` ?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Would appreciate an answer on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931505/run-webpage-on-localhost?noredirect=1)

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Appsite/website/';` Note that "Appsite" like directory and sub directories are CASE SENSITIVE.

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.php` set the `base_url()` as,

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';
```

In your view load the image as,

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/images.PNG”>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this it will take the automatically correct path of the project and set base URL

```
$site_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 'off') || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')) ? 'https' : 'http';
$site_url .= '://' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '');
$site_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = $site_url;
```