# Run webpage on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, model-view-controller, localhost

I am working on a project with MVC architecture and using the codeigniter framework. I keep on getting an error when i try running the file in the following way.

`http://localhost:9080/internship-management/sourcecode/codeigniter/index.php/vacancyManagement`

I've set the base_url in the config.php file in the config directory as follows

```
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:9080/internship-management/sourcecode/codeigniter/';  
/*
```

I have my project Internship-Management inside the C drive under www within wamp.

`C:\wamp\www\Internship-Management\SourceCode\CodeIgniter`

The project structure of the controllers are as follows

[image: codeIgniter project structure]

After trying to run the controller with the path specified in the beginning (after turning on the wamp server), I get this error

[image: error]

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated as I've been wrapping my head around this for hours now and I know this is trivial

Comment: Try [http://localhost/Internship-Management/SourceCode/CodeIgniter](http://localhost/Internship-Management/SourceCode/CodeIgniter)

Comment: @Anish I got this requested url not found error. `The requested URL /Internship-Management/SourceCode/CodeIgniteâ€Œâ€‹r/index.php/vacancyManagement was not found on this server.`

Comment: Do you have a file named `vacancyManagement.php` in your controllers folder? It seems that this is the homepage controller and the server cannot find it. Also, do you have `.htaccess` files in your path?

Comment: @AhmedEssam I've got the vacancyManagement under the controllers as highlightled in the image above(The project structure)

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter 3? if so then you need to capitalize the first letter  of your files. This requirement was added in CodeIgnier 3 https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names

Comment: @AhmedEssam in this case, I tried running another controller --> RequestController, but that didn't work as well. Will it be something wrong with the base url and the url that i am using to run the controller method?

Comment: You are clearly using a project made with CodeIgniter < v3. Go back to the link I gave and follow the steps to upgrade your code to work with CodeIgnter 3. There might be a problem with the base url, I often had difficulties setting the base url and adjusting the `.htaccess` files, but you need to upgrade your code first. After upgrading your code show us the error message you get

Comment: @Anish Thanks all. But I got it fixed. I had accidentally deleted a few codeigniter system files while moving it. Hence the error. So thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @AhmedEssam Thanks all. But I got it fixed. I had accidentally deleted a few codeigniter system files while moving it. Hence the error. So thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by a few missing CodeIgniter System Files
Within the CodeIgniter directory, the following structure needs to be maintained

```
CodeIgniter

   - .idea(directory)
   - application(directory)
   - system(directory)
   - user_guide(directory)
   - .gitignore (text file)
   - composer.json (JSON file)
   - contributing.md (MD file)
   - index.php
   - license.txt
```

Comment: Only you need is application, System, index.php only. Other all should/Can delete/Omit

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Thanks on the feedback. I'll keep these files, just incase