# Canonical URL issue on CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am developing an application in CodeIgniter. I got some issues from SEO expert. One issue is URL Canonical issue.

For Example, I can access the same content by multiple URLs.

https://seocompany.us.com/portfolio

https://seocompany.us.com/portfolio/

https://seocompany.us.com/index.php/portfolio/

https://seocompany.us.com/index.php/portfolio

How to redirect all these URLs to only 1 URL.

https://seocompany.us.com/portfolio

Comment: add htaccess for remove `index.php` will solve this issue

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122321#38122321

Comment: I have added `.htaccess` file to remove `index.php`, I can access all my controllers and its methods without `index.php` but still, I can access the same controller and its methods by using `index.php` too.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have tried that solution but not working as per my requirement.

Comment: check below answer

Comment: any update  on this

Answer (score 1):

a 301 rewrite would also work for directing them

301 --- https://seocompany.us.com/index.php/portfolio/ => https://seocompany.us.com/portfolio

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/portfolio/$ /portfolio? [L,R=301]
```

and so on

Comment: It is working fine for both the urls `https://seocompany.us.com/index.php/portfolio/` and `https://seocompany.us.com/index.php/portfolio` but not for this `https://seocompany.us.com/portfolio/`. My `.htaccess` code is `RewriteRule ^index\.php/portfolio/$ /portfolio? [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php/portfolio$ /portfolio? [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^/portfolio/$ /portfolio? [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

At end of `.htaccess` file add this. (didn't check)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seocompany.us.com/index.php/portfolio/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seocompany.us.com/portfolio/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Dear @AbdullaNilam Thanks for the solution. But unfortunately, this solution is not working. I have added the code in my `.htaccess` file.