# How to set base url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have codeigniter project and I want to upload in local server :`192.168.x.xxx`.

But I don't know how to change `base_url` in config file from localhost to local server contain IP address. How to set `$config['base_url']` ? Thanks

Comment: have a look at these, looks similar. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: I've changed it. What's wrong with my website? I upload my codeigniter project in local server but still 404 page not found.

Comment: $config['base_url']    = "ftp://".$_SERVER["192.168.3.107"]."/pkl2017";
is it right?

Comment: is it your local development environment?

Comment: i think it should be something like 'http:// .' $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . 'path_to_your_project' ;

Comment: or if u have registered domain then set it  "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE) in ....

Comment: can u post some of your code i wanna have a look?

Comment: there was syntax error in my previous comment. it should be like this.
'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . 'path_to_your_project' ;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set proper codeigniter base url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url)

Answer (score 0):

I would set it some thing like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

With domain

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourdomainname.com/';
```

End base url with `/`

> If you don't set the base url links and css, images etc will not work properly.

Comment: I set this $config['base_url']    =  'http:// .' $_SERVER['192.168.3.107'] . 'pkl2017/keluhan.php' ; but still error

Comment: Don't use ip address

Comment: Also make sure you have named your controllers, models etc correct where only the first letter is upper case only class and filename explained here. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: How I set base_url? because that ip address as my website

Answer (score 0):

try it like this :

**index.php :**

```
define('APP_URL', ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https' : 'http') . "://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}".str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

**config.php :**

```
$config['base_url'] = APP_URL;
```

reference : [How to set proper codeigniter base url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.3.107/pkl2017';
```

**NOTE:** `pkl2017` is your project folder name.