# How to link to another page when clicking button

Tags: codeigniter

login.php (controller)

```
class login extends CI_Controller {
   public function index()
   {
     $this->load->view('login');
   }

   public function Click()
   {
      $action = $this->input->post('register'); // $_POST['start']; also works.
      if($action)
      {
          $this->load->view('register');
      }
   }
}
```

login.php(views)

```
<form action="" class="loginForm" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="form-control" value="Login" name="login">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="form-control" value="Buat Akun" name="register" >
    </div>
</form>
```

how can I change my view to register.php after clicking register button. The error is I keep back to login page after clicking register.

Comment: If your ip shows in url that means you must set the base url in config.php as it recommends it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450302/how-to-set-base-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: If you are looking for a solution based on your html markup, I think you need to change button type to "button" and add onClick javascript event that uses window.location to redirect to register url. Right now submit type button is always posting to the form action url.

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this :**

In `Login` controller :

```
      public function register()
      {
          $this->load->view('register');
      }
```

**In view:**

```
<form action="" class="loginForm" method="POST">
 <div class="input-group">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" class="form-control" value="Login" name="login">
   <a href="<?php echo base_url('login/register');?>" id="submit" class="form-control"  name="register" >Register</a>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This site can’t be reached
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: have u properly setup url and .htaccess

Comment: I don't setup that, so my url when I click register http://my-url/register. it's supposed be: http://localhost:8000/myurl-url/register

Comment: and when I try http://localhost:8000/my-url/register. it's redirect to XAMPP dashboard, I'am very confuse about that.

Comment: you have to properly set your config file and add .htaccess file in your project folder : pls read : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: I have add this too .htaccess but it still redirect to dashboard <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my-url/
</IfModule>
do you know what's my problem?

Comment: It may be the htaccess issue. To confirm that, try remove htaccess file and access url by adding index.php
http://localhost:8000/projectfolder/index.php/remaining-url

Comment: also if u are using htaccess then rewrite_module (mod_rewrite) need to be enabled in apache config

Comment: Add this in .htaccess:   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: set   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_folder_name/'; $config['index_page'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mod_rewrite module in apache

Please follow below mention step to enable mod_rewrite module:

1) Find the “httpd.conf” file under the “conf” folder inside the Apache’s installation folder.

2) Find the following line “#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so” in the “httpd.conf” file.You can do this easily by searching the keyword “mod_rewrite” from find menu.

3) Remove the “#” at the starting of the line, “#” represents that line is commented.

4) Now restart the apache server.

5) You can see now “mod_rewrite” in the Loaded Module section while doing “phpinfo()”.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
In Login Controller:

class Login extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->input->post('login') == 'Login'){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }else{
        $this->register();
    }
}

public function register(){
    $this->load->view('register');
}
```

}

In View :