# PHP base_url in Alt Tag

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

I have `alt` and `title` tags that contain data from a table that are appended with the `base_url` that I would like to remove. When I do so the `alt` tags show up empty. Currently the is what the code is:

```
<img title="<?php print_r(base_url().
        $promo5['data'][0]->CarouselImageTitleAtribute);?>" 
     alt = "<?php print_r(base_url().$promo5['data']
       [0]->CarouselImageAltAtribute);?>'/.
```

The result is this:

```
<img title="https://www.example.com/Click here to read about 
           our custom products" 
     alt = "https://www.example.com/Custom colored products"/>
```

I need to remove the https://www.example.com/ and only keep the value in the table (CarouselImageAltAtribute) I have tried using

```
<?php echo $promo5->CarouselImageAltAtribute; ?>
```

With no luck.

Comment: Thanks, i am not that familiar with PHP and  was frustrated with the developer dragging his feet on this so i thought I would fix it myself. But I see the logic and appreciate you help; it is working! :)

Comment: Just want to add for those who may be unaware that base_url() is a PHP function available with codeigniter  and is not a built-in PHP function; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122285#38122285

Comment: B. L.  please mark the answer as you said it worked for you.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove `base_url()` code from `alt=""`  and `title=""` like below:-

```
<img title = "<?php echo $promo5['data'][0]->CarouselImageTitleAtribute;?>"
   alt = "<?php echo $promo5['data'][0]->CarouselImageAltAtribute;?>"/>
```