# Base url is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i use base_url as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost';
```

It redirects to localhost/login/validate and shows object not found. Any idea why? But it works perfectly in live server when i set base_url to domain.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://designhub.com.np/educare';
```

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name'; `

Comment: Exact duplicate of **[Set up the base url in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter)**

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in config.php

```
$ark_root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ark_root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $ark_root;


$root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

/*assets path*/
define('HTTP_CSS_PATH', $config['base_url'].'assets/css/');
define('HTTP_DOC_PATH', $config['base_url'].'assets/docs/');
define('HTTP_IMAGES_PATH', $config['base_url'].'assets/images/');
define('HTTP_JS_PATH', $config['base_url'].'assets/js/');
define('HTTP_IMG_PATH', $config['base_url'].'assets/img/');
```

you can use it local as well as on server too

Comment: It's a cool trick, but Codeigniter's code itself actually discourages this behavior as it can be not secure. If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production! (From application\config\config.php)

Answer (score 0):

When your on a local host set it some thing like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

When use live domain

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/';
```

Comment: Thanks worlfgang1983, changes works but there is nothing in dashboard

Comment: Can you be more clear please but there is nothing in dashboard??

Comment: Did you follow codeigniter file and naming way explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @DipeshShrestha Also try with index.php in url `http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/dashboard` if that works then you need a suitable htaccess for your project

Comment: designhub.com.np/educare
login: admin@gmail.com
pwd: admin

you can login and see dashboard there.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the folder name in which the project files are: (with localhost)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_folder_name/';
```

As your live server has your project files under root folder like public_html so you can use base_url as you mentioned.

But with local, write folder name after `localhost` as I have mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer have any different with *@wolfgang1983*'s answer??

Comment: i changed it and now dashboard is empty, not sure why

Comment: It will be difficult to assume @DipeshShrestha, what is URL when you land on dashboard?

Comment: after login it redirects to http://localhost/myproject/dashboard. but dashboard is empty