# Codeigniter current_url avoid jpg etc

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm quite new in codeigniter. I'm using the `current_url()` function to preserve previously viewed page's URL. But the function (I think from different ajax calls) gives i.e. jpg files' url.

Like this:

> /uploads/default/files/HTC.jpg

I'd like to avoid these and just preserve those URLs which are used in Browser's URL bar.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up the base url in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `current_url()` and then saving the output of this function somewhere for later retrieval.

So you could, before you save the string, perform a regex check to see if it fits the format you want:

```
$pattern = '~.+\.[a-zA-Z]{0,3}$~';
$string = current_url();

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

if (empty($matches)) {
    // We can save the url
}
```

The regex will hit on Urls which end in a `.` with zero to 3 letters:

- `HTC.jpg` will fail
- `la/di.php` will fail
- `la/items/2` will pass

Comment: Glad i could help. Could you please accept this answer if it fits your needs?