# 404 Page Not Found CodeIgniter2 in Host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to upload a small application I made to a host (http://fetratel.com/gestionreportev2/) but for some reason, the only controller I can call in the 'route.php' is the 'welcome' (by default) `$ route ['default_controller'] =" welcome "`). When I put the name of another driver does not get it

- I tried, using the name of the driver in uppercase and I shot
  "Page 404 not found The page you requested was not found."
- I tried using the name of the controller in Lowercase and the screen appears empty.

My configuration is the following:

```
gestionreportev2
| application
| | config
| | | config.php
| | | routes.php
| | controllers
| | | export.php
| | models
| | | exportmodel.php
| | views
| | | export
| | | | index.php
|.htaccess
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.fetratel.com/gestionreportev2/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "export";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Controller:

export.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Export extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('Exportmodel','ticket');
}

public function index()
{     
$title = ['title' => 'Listado a Exportar'];
$this->load->view('Header', $title);
$this->load->view('Export/Index');
$this->load->view('Foother');
}

public function ajax_list()
{
    ...
}

}
```

This app with config parameters data base local run OK.

I appreciate all the support in advance.

Comment: Try with `RewriteBase /gestionreportev2/`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `.htacess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I made the suggested setting in the .htaccess but still can not find the controller.

Comment: it's working when fine, I add `index.php` in your URL http://fetratel.com/index.php/gestionreportev2/

Comment: But, this url fetratel.com/index.php/gestionreportev2 is similar to the main page http://fetratel.com/index.php or http://fetratel.com/

Comment: those two links are not in CodeIgniter. you're doing wrong that's why 404

Comment: Could it be because the main application is based on ZEND framework?
I just try to create another application in codeigniter on the same server.

Comment: there is no issues like that. define project URL and all this will get fixed **[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122321#38122321)**