# How to URL Rewrite from virtual host setup to non-virtual host setup

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a CodeIgniter app working properly on my local machine using virtual hosts, and I access it via `http://mysite.local`

I am trying to get it to work on a different machine, where for some reason I cannot use virtual hosts, so I have to access it via `http://x.x.x.x/mysite` where `x.x.x.x` is an IP address and `mysite` is the folder name on the machine. The page displays, but the assets are 404. The browser is trying to retrieve, for example, `http://x.x.x.x/asset.css` when it's supposed to be `http://x.x.x.x/mysite/asset.css`

How do I change the .htaccess so that the assets are retrieved properly?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned ***I am trying to get it to work on a different machine*** and ***where x.x.x.x is an IP address and mysite is the folder name on the machine*** you have to set the base URL of respective machine path.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://x.x.x.x/mysite/';
```

Read [Set up the base URL in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122321#38122321)