# CSS and JavaScript Both are not loading in mobile view using codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, mobile

I am new to codeigniter but so for, I have used it well not until I have tried to view it on other devices.

This is the problem:

Web:
[Broswer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qma7.png) | [Browser (Responsive Design View)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zzZn.png)

Mobile: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOoVz.jpg) | [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52xyd.jpg)

_htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Page Controller:

```
<?php
    class Pages extends CI_controller{
        public function view($page = 'home'){
            if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did You Add this line into your Header View ? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                                                                                You Can check in various browsers also. try remove your cdn and attach scripts and css via locally.

Comment: set up base url like this will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122321#38122321

Comment: Make sure you have set your base url correct in the config.php don't touch the htaccess inside application folder.

Comment: @pardeep I have already added that line on my header.

Comment: @DeadManAlive - Base url are all set up just like what you have on the link

Comment: show me the console errors

Comment: can you put view file here

Comment: is that ip Address public or local? have you checked it?

Comment: @silent - No console errors.

Comment: @Ayyappaamara - Local address. I have my laptop as a server (xampp) and I accessed the app via mobile thru wifi but it only shows the plain html page without styles.

Comment: You Can use ngrok for test what is the problem actually is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add relative path of css and is not absolute path , if you are adding CDN path then make sure to allow xampp to access internet. I guess you have given path of local host or windows path but trying to access through IP in LAN that's why it is giving problem and solution is relative path.

Comment: I have set my assets (css, js and etc) locally for me to load directly from my computer the files without internet. Before I migrated my application to codeigniter, it was all working well also on mobile view and after I integrated my application to codeigniter, the mobile view messed up. It's like something is prohibiting the app to load those assets.

Comment: Can you please check the footer wether it is showing on you plain text htlm page or not by adding some extra data. I guess your header and footer file unable to load . Either it may be due to incorrect configured url or it may be not in the correct accessible directory. You should install some parser or debugging tool to find error log :)

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your answer. I can't help but laugh of how stupid I am after I figured out the one that works. Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: I seen your answer and yes it happens when you try to access outside of localhost you should provide your server ip. And i am glade that you fix your problem :) welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

After how many hours of research. I have finally found the answer. It is too simple that I even laugh of how stupid I am.

When I view the page source from my mobile device, it shows that the base_url of the headers are LOCALHOST which is why the device cannot find the css/js files from the mobile device. In order for the headers to work, you must change first the base_url to your device's IP ADDRESS. That should do the work.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and successfully fixed it.
Just change base_url 'localhost' to device's IP ADDRESS just like the Jeff Yan said