# form_validation not working where everything in ok in my code, Kindly help me

Tags: codeigniter

autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation');
```

controller:

```
class Adminlogin extends CI_controller
{
public function new_user()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required|min_length[8]|max_length[15]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {

                $Name    = $this->input->POST('name');  
                $Email = $this->input->POST('email');
                $Password = $this->input->POST('password');

                $data = array('Name' => $Name, 'Email' => $Email, 'Password' => $Password);
                $this->load->model('login_model');              
                $this->login_model->newuser_data($data);

                //redirect('public/login_form');
                $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            }
            else
            {
                echo "not done";
            }
        }
```

if I remove condition from validation then form works and data in traveled and when I apply condition on validation then form not working data is also not traveling without showing any error.

model:

```
public function newuser_data($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
        $query = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

view:

```
 <?php echo form_open('adminlogin/new_user'); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <center><h3>Create User!</h3>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'name','name'=>'name','placeholder'=>'Name','class'=>'form-control contact-form','value'=>set_value('name')]) ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'email','name'=>'email','placeholder'=>'Email','class'=>'form-control contact-form','value'=>set_value('Email')]) ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'Password','name'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Password','class'=>'form-control contact-form','value'=>set_value('Password')]) ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('password'); ?> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-right button-submit btn-submit">
                    <?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'submit','value'=>'Login','class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: $data = array('Name' => $Name, 'Email' => $Email, 'Password' => $Password);
                $this->load->model('login_model');              
                $this->login_model->newuser_data($data);

Does lower casing the key of Arrays help ?

Comment: data is passing to database it has not any issue, after applying validation it not works.

Comment: Replace - `echo "not done";` - with - `echo validation_errors();` - so you know the validation error(s) you have.

Comment: I think you want the first argument of `set_value(..)` all lowercase.

Comment: Hey @ShabhiNaqvi I think you need to load **form helper**. `$this->load->helper('form');`

Comment: @vishalkumar it is autoloaded $autoload['helper'] = array('url','captcha','form');

Answer (score 1):

```
class Adminlogin extends CI_controller
{
public function new_user()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required|min_length[8]|max_length[15]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()!=FALSE)
            {

                $Name    = $this->input->POST('name');  
                $Email = $this->input->POST('email');
                $Password = $this->input->POST('password');

                $data = array('Name' => $Name, 'Email' => $Email, 'Password' => $Password);
                $this->load->model('login_model');              
                $this->login_model->newuser_data($data);

                //redirect('public/login_form');
                $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            }
            else
            {
                echo "not done";
            }
        }
```

---

Change in if condition

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
```

to

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()!=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

change this to

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
```

to

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
```

Read -  [Form Validation in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller)

Comment: index.php is removed from URL?

Comment: then add `index.php` to your form URL or remove it with `.htaccess`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122321#38122321

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
```

to

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()===TRUE)
```

Comment: When you try does it echo the message  "not done" as you've defined? If not, put this if ($this->form_validation->run()===TRUE) as I mentioned before, and check whether you have configured the "form_validation" library. That is; $autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');

Answer (score 0):

Change your statement

**From**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
```

**To**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
```

**OR**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this controller

```
class Adminlogin extends CI_controller
{
public function new_user()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required|min_length[8]|max_length[15]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
            {

                echo 'Not done';
            }
            else
            {
                $Name    = $this->input->POST('name');  
                $Email = $this->input->POST('email');
                $Password = $this->input->POST('password');

                $data = array('Name' => $Name, 'Email' => $Email, 'Password' => $Password);
                $this->load->model('login_model');              
                $this->login_model->newuser_data($data);


            $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
        }
    }
```