# Is it possible that ci url will not work with index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

Is it possible that ci url will not work with index.php.I dont want to add index.php in url. If someone adds index.php in url it should not work.I have tried many methods . Please give me suggestion.
I have tried but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

for e.g

if i use below url This should work..............

```
`example.com/abc`
```

if i use below url shouldn't work

```
`example.com/index.php/abc`
```

Comment: <p>Please check the below link.</p>
Click [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url ]

Comment: If you want simple solution, just rename the `index.php` file to something else and modify the `RewriteRule` to point ro that file, better than writing complex unnecessary rewrite conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in the top of the index.php.  I think this will solve your problem.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index.php') !== false){
    header('location: http://xyx.com/404');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create .htaccess file in your root directory And keep this code into it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Open application/config/config.php

```
    //find the below code   
$config['index_page'] = "index.php" 
//replace with the below code
$config['index_page'] = ""

/find the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
//replace with the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/website/';
$config['index_page'] = '';

# If Live site
# $config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
```

**In `.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> Check my answer on another question **[Set up the base URL in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122321#38122321)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# 403 Forbidden for index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code than..

change the following in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Now open .htaccess file and replace with below code..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

if above index line do not work the replace the line with new code. Because .htaccess depend on server

```
// Replace last .htaccess line with this line
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectname
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Change in config file:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: are you working in local ? which one you using xamp or wamp ? it work with xamp only and if website is on server my code will work definitely.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by saying `url shouldn't work` should it redirect to another or be replaced?

`url shouldn't work` - i think you must say to a user (to a crawler) that there is an error in this link, if the link is already indexed, tell crawler that this is `404 not found` page, and it will stop indexing that pages. You can't disable `index.php/foo` totally, because all requests are going through `index.php` (i believe, if you are using routing)

Here is replacement example - https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=04dcf45c-32e9-5c29-b706-5869cd369ffd

Input url `http://ex.com/index.php/abc`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.php/(.*) /404 [L] #send user to not found page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Output url `http://ex.com/404`

Comment: See the link in my answer

Comment: wht will happen . In admin area i am using index.php . what about that ?

Comment: i edited my answer, tested it on my router, when the url is something like `ex.com/index.php/foo/bar/baz` it will request the `ex.com/404` page, but when the url is like `ex.com/foo/bar/baz` it will request the `ex.com/index.php/foo/bar/baz`. So in both cases url will request page through `index.php` which is right i think. I believe you have got one enter point to the website.
Give it a try it should work

Comment: well it depends on your routing system.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,END]

RewriteRule ^index\.php* - [F]
```