# Cant get URL parameters in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I tried to access an id from a URL `"myfolder/mycontroller/mymethode/123"` which I call into an AJAXcall.

I cannot access them, in `"mycontroller"` under the `"mymethode"`. I tried to output `$_GET, $_POST, $this->input->get(), $this->input->post()`, but all array are empty.

In the `Controller/mycontroller` I have this

```
public function mymethode($listid=false)
{
      echo "listid: $listid";
      print_r($_GET);
      print_r($_POST);
      print_r($this->input->get());
      print_r($this->input->post());
}
```

The Ajax call is this and is ok with Status 200.

```
$.ajax({
                          url: http://mydomein.com/myfolder/mycontroller/mymethode/123,
                          type: "POST",
                          method: 'post',
                          data: form + "&" + additional_data + csrfName + "=" + csrfHash, 
                          dataType: 'json',
                          cache: false,                         
                         success: function(res){...
```

If I tried to open the URL directly, I have the same problem.

What can the reason for it be?

Comment: Even your `$listid` is empty?  Have a look at your `config.php` and check your `$config['uri_protocol']` setting.  You may need to change this to get things to work.

Comment: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
on other pages it works, so i think there must something special with this!?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_SERVER)`, that should show you the value of `REQUEST_URI` (and other things) to see if the `uri_protocol` is right.

Comment: is this HMVC ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this (if this is not HMVC)

**in route.php**

```
# You may need first route since you're accepting null on method
$route['mymethode] = 'mycontroller/mymethode';
$route['mymethode/(:num)'] = 'mycontroller/mymethode/$1';
```

**In AJAX**

```
url: http://mydomein.com/mymethode/123,
```

> [Make sure your sites run without `index.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853416/4595675)

**In controller**

```
public function mymethode($listid=null)
```