# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500, Codeigniter project

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send a call using ajax but in Chrome it is rising error but in firefox there is no error. But still it can't calling the method.
THis append shows  7 divs, but some div gets loaded but some of div keeps loading and console shows error 500

```
    //get recent posts via ajax controller class
public function get_recent_articles($cr_post_id,$category,$limit,$offset)
{
    $recent_post=$this->Post_model->get_recent_articles($cr_post_id,$category,$limit,$offset);
    return $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_output(json_encode($recent_post));
}
```

Here is view part

```
$('#recent_post_cat_2').show(); 
$('#recent_post_cat_2').append('<div id="recent_post_cat_2_preloader" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;padding:15px 0px;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i></div>');
```

Here is Ajax function

```
/* START - get_recent_articles*/
function get_recent_articles(category,div_id,limit)
{       
    //prepare url   
    url="<?php echo "/./home-recent-articles-filter-cat/";?>"+category+"/"+limit+"/";           $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,      
    success: function(data){
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));               
            if(data.status=="success")
            {                   

                prepared_posts_data=prepare_cards(category,data.data,3);
                $(div_id+'_preloader').remove();
                $(div_id).append(prepared_posts_data);
                $(div_id).show();                           

                var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
                    threshold: 50,
                    callback_load: function(e) {
                      // console.log($(e).attr("data-original") + " loaded" );
                    }
                }); 
            }
            else{
                 console.log("no posts available");                  
            }
        }
});
}
```

Comment: KeyPoint: some div gets easily loaded, but some times only loader works.

Comment: where is your $offset param? in ajax url

Comment: I don't have , actually am new on this. That is developed projects already.

Comment: then pass it as default param i.e $offset=''

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this line

`url="<?php echo "/./home-recent-articles-filter-cat/";?>"+category+"/"+limit+"/";`

Codeigniter URL does not look like this. It contains at least 3 parameters on it(unless `index` function)

1. base URL
2. controller name
3. method name

---

So it should be something like this

```
url = <?= base_url(); ?>.'controller_name/get_recent_articles'
```

---

Make sure these  are loaded

1. URL helper
2. `short_tag=On` in  PHP.ini

---

Check these

1. [Set up the base URL in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122186/set-up-the-base-url-in-codeigniter/38122321#38122321)

Comment: I guess that is for passing para through url.

Comment: yes you can add those next to URL ex `url = <?= base_url(); ?>.'controller_name/get_recent_articles/'.5/10/2/0`

Comment: home-recent-articles-filter-cat is name of view file

Comment: use proper controller name. see codeigniter tutorials.