# Route not found in condeigniter but route exsit?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter and my route not working. Route are exists in route file. but when io hit url I get not found error. My Route file is

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'error/page/e404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['([a-z]+)/testimonials/index'] = 'testimonial/home/index';
$route['([a-z]+)/all_auctions'] = 'all_auction/all_auctions/index';
$route['([a-z]+)/all_products'] = 'all_product/all_products/index';
$route['([a-z]+)/page/contact-us'] = 'page/contact/index';
$route['([a-z]+)/page/(.+)'] = 'page/page/index/$2';
$route['([a-z]+)/auctions/winners/(:num)'] = 'auctions/winners/index/$2';
$route['([a-z]+)/feed'] = 'feed/index/index';
$route['([a-z]+)/feed/winners'] = 'feed/index/winners';
$route['([a-z]+)/feed/winners/(:num)'] = 'feed/index/winners/$2';
$route['([a-z]+)/auctions/closed/(.+)-(:num)'] = 'auctions/winners/details/$3';
$route['([a-z]+)/all_auctions/(:num)'] = 'all_auction/all_auctions/index/$2';
$route['([a-z]+)/all_auctions/upcoming_auctions'] = 'all_auction/all_auctions/upcoming_auctions';
$route['([a-z]+)/all_auctions/upcoming_auctions/(:num)'] = 'all_auction/all_auctions/upcoming_auctions/$2';
$route['([a-z]+)/auctions/upcoming_auction/(.+)-(:num)'] = 'auctions/details/upcoming_auction_detail/$3';
$route['([a-z]+)/auctions/(.+)-(:num)'] = 'auctions/details/index/$3';
$route['([a-z]+)/products/(.+)-(:num)'] = 'products/details/index/$3';
$route['([a-z]+)/referer/(.+)'] = 'referer/index/$1';
$route['([a-z]+)/landingpage/(.+)'] = 'landingpage/index/$2';
$route['([a-z]+)/(:num)'] = 'home/index/$2';


$route['404_override'] = 'error/page/e404';  

$route[ADMIN_LOGIN_PATH] = 'login/admin';  
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH] = 'dashboard/admin';
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/profile'] = "dashboard/admin/profile";
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/logout'] = 'login/admin/logout';
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/forgot'] = 'login/password';
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/reset'] = "login/admin/reset";
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/newsletter/subscriber'] = "newsletter/subscriber/index";
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/newsletter/subscriber/(:num)'] = "newsletter/subscriber/index/$1";
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/newsletter/subscriber/(.+)'] = "newsletter/subscriber/$1";
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/newsletter/template'] = "newsletter/subscriptiontemplate/index";
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/newsletter/template/(.+)'] = "newsletter/subscriptiontemplate/$1";
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/(.+)'] = '$1/admin/$2';
$route[ADMIN_DASHBOARD_PATH.'/reload'] = "login/admin/reload";



// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^en/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^en$'] = $route['default_controller'];


$route['app/([a-z_]+)'] = "app/$1";
$route['app/([a-z_]+)/([a-z_]+)'] = "app/$1/$2";
```

and I am trying route

```
http://localhost/en
```

and I get this error How can I solve this issue
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly this cause by URL navigates with `index.php`.

In **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And in **`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

> Read more : [Set up the base url in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38122321/4595675)