# Codeigniter (only) wildcard routes not working in sub-folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, routes

I have this wildcard route:

```
$route['izvlacenje-2022/(:any)']['GET'] = 'WinnersController/draw_screen/$1';
```

that works fine locally, but not on the server in the staging sub-folder where it gives me 404 error:

```
http://project.localhost/izvlacenje-2022/renovate // works fine locally
https://our-domain/staging/izvlacenje-2022/renovate // does not work in staging folder, gives 404
```

Other, non wildcard routes work fine. For example:

```
$route['intro']['GET'] = 'LandingsController/index';

https://our-domain/staging/intro // works fine
```

httacces:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /staging
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|gallery|json|slider|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also, in the config file I set the index_page value to blank, but it does not work either way:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: did you set your `base_url` properly ?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Yes I did, but as far as I know, base_url doesn't have impact on routing anyways.

Comment: Yes. It does. Did you try with normal `.htaccess`?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Depends on what you mean by normal. This is the htaccess I used until today, and it also didn't work:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: Seems have to check the code. check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38122321/4595675